# Excel VBA that saves values and updates values if there is duplicates based on a date

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to add a macro to the display mail button that updates the "Table" sheet with the value in C11 and C23 in the screenshot based on the date in K2:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the "Table" sheet I want to update:

[image]

The way I want to add the numbers to the table is to paste the value in C11 into rows 10, 11, 12 and paste C23 into row 13,14,15. Based on the date in K2 in the corresponging column in row 9 in the "Table"sheet.
And then if the date is already in the table just update corresponding values. If the date is not in the table add it the the next available column in the "Table" sheet.

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Edit:
The closest I have to a solution to far is the following:

```
Sub Save values()

*If L2 not in D9 Increase column try if L2 = D9 paste value else if empty paste*

    Worksheets("Intradag likviditet").Range("L2").Copy Worksheets("Table").Range("D9")
    Worksheets("Intradag likviditet").Range("C11").Copy Worksheets("Table").Range("D10")
    Worksheets("Intradag likviditet").Range("C23").Copy Worksheets("Table").Range("D13")

End Sub
```

The column L2 is a column where I have converted K2 to another format with =TEXT(K2;"YYYYMMDD")

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I have made an edit with an answer to your question

Comment: say, sheet "Intradag likviditet" is set as shSrc, and sheet "TABLE" is set as shTrg. Then check `set c = shTrg.rows(9).find(shSrc.range("L2").value,lookat:=xlwhole) : if c is nothing then set c = shTrg.cells(9,columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(0,1)` ---> here, the variable c will be a cell in shTrg row 9 which has same value with shSrc cell L2 OR a blank cell next to the last cell with data in row 9 in shTrg. (continue)

Comment: Then you do the copy process : `c.value = shSrc.range("L2").value` --> the row9 whatever column of c in shTrg will have the same value with shSrc cell L2. It doesn't matter if c already has value, because the value will still the same. Then `c.offset(1,0).resize(1,3).value = shSrc.range("C11").value:  c.offset(4,0).resize(1,3).value = shSrc/range("C23").value` It fill the rest of the row by offseting and resizing the c variable. **Not tested** in my side.

Comment: Thank you @karma, I will test this and give an update when I have something to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the issue I hope this helps someone else in the future:

I changed the data structure to this:

[image]

This is the VBA code I ended up using:

```
Sub Update_FM_Values()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Found As Boolean


Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'assuming the code is running in the workbook being updated
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table_FM") 'change "Sheet1" to the actual name of your sheet
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Intradag likviditet")

'Define dates
Dim Current_Date As Date
Dim LCR_Value As Long
Dim Intradag_likviditet As Long

Current_Date = ws1.Range("M2").Value
LCR_Value = ws1.Range("N2").Value
Intradag_likviditet = ws1.Range("O2").Value

'Find the last row of data in the sheet
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Found = False
'Loop through each row to check if the date already exists
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) = Current_Date Then
        'Update the values
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = LCR_Value
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = Intradag_likviditet
        Found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'If the date was not found, append a new row with the current date, LCR, and Intradag_likviditet
If Not Found Then
    ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1) = Current_Date 'assumes the system date format matches the format in your sheet
    ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2) = LCR_Value 'replace with the actual LCR value
    ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3) = Intradag_likviditet 'replace with the actual Intradag_likviditet value
End If

End Sub
```

Feel free to ask questions I you want me to explain what I did in more detail